# Java convert html with css+js to pdf

Tags: java, javascript, html, pdf, converters

I am developing a JSF project and I have a doubt about reporting.

The idea is to offer the users reports in both HTML and PDF formats.

This should work developing the reports in HTML+CSS+JS and whenever a user needs a PDF report just convert the HMTL+CSS+JS to PDF.

Does somebody know a free Java library for converting the HTML to PDF?
This should be blind to the user.

Other proposals are accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

better to use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) tool to convert your HTML to pdf

Comment: I have tried with wkhtmltopdf but i am getting troubles since it does process the CSS but not the JS. Is there any way of process the JS before the PDF is created?

Comment: Finally I opted for using pure HTML/CSS graphs and wkhtmltopdf. Thanks for the solution

Comment: The above project for wkhtmltopdf is moved to [wkhtmltopdf.org](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Free solution: [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) - uses WebKit under the hood.

Commercial solution: PrinceXML - uses it's own ACID 2 compliant HTML rendering engine.

Answer (score 2):

Apache FOP would be one solution which is an XSLT based solution although it does not support HTML5. Flying Saucer, wkhtmltopdf are some free solutions which are worthy a try. Commercial libraries like PriceXML offer support to CSS3. Pdfcrowd is yet another commercial solution.

Answer (score 1):

Would [Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) be an option? From the same report file you can generate many formats, PDF and HTML (+CSS) are two of them. Plus there is a GUI [report designer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer).

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/)

It internally uses iText and pretty good library